# Handling NULL values in R regression

Tags: r, null, regression

I am trying to perform a regression on a data set that has `NULL` values. For example, I am running the following:

```
reg2<-lm(yvar~xvar1+xvar2,data=test_all)
```

And I am getting the following error:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
>     0 (non-NA) cases

I think I am getting this error because certain variables have `NULL` in some instances. Is there any way to get around this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you share some of your data with dput? Not tested, but you could try `reg2<-lm(yvar~xvar1+xvar2,data=test_all, na.action = na.omit)`, but you might need to force all of your `NULL` values to `NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have `R` drop all observations containing `NULL`, `NaN`, `NA` etc. by calling `lm` this way:

```
reg2 <- lm(yvar~xvar1 + xvar2, data = test_all[complete.cases(test_all),])
```

`complete.cases` gives a vector containing `TRUE` if a row in a data frame contains only real data, and a `FALSE` if it contains at least one `NULL`, etc.

Be aware though, that if your data frame contains a column you do not use in your linear model, but which *does* contain a missing value, this row will be dropped from your data frame. You wouldn't want that to happen.

If that is the case, then you will need to do something like this:

```
test_all2 <- test_all[,c("yvar", "xvar1", "xvar2")]
reg2 <- lm(yvar ~ xvar1 + xvar2, data = test_all2[complete.cases(test_all2),])
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!